# PHP - How to find the Auto Increment Array id to unset

Tags: php, arrays, session, increment, unset

I am using a form to create several arrays in a Session. Each time the form is submitted a new $_SESSION['item'][] is made containing each new array. The code for this:

```
$newitem = array (
    'id' => $row_getshoppingcart['id'] ,
    'icon' => $row_getimages['icon'],
    'title' => $row_getimages['title'],
    'medium' => $row_getshoppingcart['medium'],
    'size' => $row_getshoppingcart['size'],
    'price' => $row_getshoppingcart['price'],
    'shipping' => $row_getshoppingcart['shipping']);

$_SESSION['item'][] = $newitem;
```

There could be any number of item arrays based on how many times the user submits the form. Any ideas how can I get the value of the array key that is being put in place of the [] in the session variable? I am trying to create a remove from cart option and cannot figure out how to reference that particular array in the session to unset it.

I am currently displaying the items as such:

```
<?php foreach ( $_SESSION['item'] AS $item )
echo $item['title'];
echo $item['icon'];
```

and so on...

Thank you in advance for your time. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foreach($_SESSION['item'] as $key => $value)` will enable you to seperate the key and value, and ofcourse, to access the value current key has.

To extend this with an example, consider following code:

```
<?php
$exArray = array("foo"=>"bar", "foo2"=>"bar2);

foreach($exArray as $arrKey => $arrValue):
    echo "The key ".$arrKey." has the value of ".$arrValue."<br />\n";
endforeach;
?>
```

will output:

`The key foo has the value of bar.`

`The key foo2 has the value of bar2.`

However, in the same way, if the $arrValue variable is known to hold an array, it will keep it's content. To loop through that second array, you will need to loop it through another foreach statement.

Comment: How would the echo statement reflect those changes as well as still echo the additional information?

Comment: Got it, a little tricky getting the outputs right because of the array structure but it was my idiocy not your code. Thank you very much for your help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just specify an index name in your foreach

```
foreach ($_SESSION['item'] as $idx => $item) {
    var_dump($item);
    var_dump($_SESSION['item'][$idx]);
}
```

The var_dumps will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = array_keys($arr);
$count = count($var);
$lastKey = $var[$count - 1];
```

That work for you?

Comment: A better solution would probably just be to give the array key the `id` value